# Como gerar planilhas do Microsoft Excel no .NET Core?

Tags: c#, microsoft-excel, .net-core

Preciso gerar planilhas do Microsoft Excel através do `.NET Core`, existe alguma biblioteca que faça isso?

Nas minhas pesquisas só consegui encontrar o [Open XML SDK](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK) da própria Microsoft, mas o suporte ao .NET Core ainda está em desenvolvimento.

Answer (score 2):

Como você mesmo mencionou, este suporte ainda está em aberto. Como pode ser visto nas [Issues do repositório](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK/issues/65) no GitHub.

Existem duas alternativas:

1. [Uma implementação standard do Open XML SDK 2.5](https://github.com/xrkolovos/Open-XML-SDK-for-NET-Platform-Standard). Você precisa clonar e buildar para utilizar os pacotes.
2. Outra alternativa, que tem sido usada tanto pra ler, como exportar é o [`EPPlus`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus). Que pode ser obtido via nuget.

*obs.: vale ressaltar novamente que são alternativas.*

Comment: já se passaram algum tempo e o projeto Core me parece estar mais maduro, temos alguma solução solidas para este problema?

Comment: Hoje tem o epplus.core https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus.Core/

Comment: Olá!! Vocês tem usado qual alternativa pra dotnet core atualmente?